# Deactivate wiki pages

Tags: 2010, wiki-pages

Wiki pages is the functionality that we can enable in SharePoint site from features. Is there any way by which we can prevent from creating wiki pages. No one should be able to create wiki pages.

Or can say we want to completely disable the wiki library and pages feature(Please anything except deactivating from manage site features).

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

YOu can create wiki pages when you go to site Contents / Site Pages via clicking new document. To disable that functionality, you have to go into the libary Settings and then delete the Content type "Wiki Page" or go under Advantage Settings and set it to read only.

Comment: Making a content type as Read Only doesn't stop users from creating items from those content types, it would only prevent users from modifying  the content type.

Comment: Thanks Hitesh for information, could you please help more for this concern.

Comment: If no one at all should be able to create them, I would remove the content type completely from my site, rather than at the library level. You would first have to delete all existing Wiki Pages from libraries and from both recycle bins.

Comment: @ErinL When I tried to delete content type I got an error that this is part of application feature. I tried to do it from site settings-> site content type, is it the right place from where to do that or it has to be done from somewhere else.

Comment: It sounds like the content type is being used by a custom feature. Are there any custom features listed on the same page as the Wiki Page feature? Do you know if anyone developed custom code?

Comment: My first thought was also to delete the Content type, but then I found the read only Option, however that does not work. It seems that only deletion will work, sorry. If you can not delete a Content type, it seems that it is used, maybe by a wiki page. 
Another Option would be to disable this Content type, under "Layout and Templates" ... but this seems only available for Enterprise wiki sites...

Comment: Yes the content type was in use by wiki page. But one more concern from my side is by deleting the content type at one site will it get disable for that particular site only ? I want it for complete application.  @user3352632-

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way of preventing users from creating wiki pages altogether out of the box in my opinion.

However, There are two ways you can achieve your requirement.

**Option 1** - **Using some JavaScript and CSS tricks in a Delegate Control**, you can restrict the users from creating wiki pages in your site. This can be done by adding a delegate control to your site that would sit in your document libraries and check for its `SPLISTTEMPLATETYPE`. If it's value is WebPageLibrary (Wiki Page Library - 119), then New Document link on the view and the New Document and Upload Document commands on the ribbon can be disabled or hidden using JavaScript and CSS.

**Pros**

- Will work even on the newly created wiki page libraries

**Cons**

- Would require writing code.

**Option 2 - By Breaking Permission Inheritance**

- Go to your Wiki Page Library Settings -> Permissions for this Library
- Under Permissions tab on the ribbon, Click on **Stop Inheriting Permissions**
- Click Ok on the dialog box.
- Select all the users and groups you want to restrict from creating pages, and click on **Edit user permissions** in the ribbon.
- Assign the users and groups selected **Read** permissions.

**Pros**

- Completely Out of box and no-code solution, easy to implement

**Cons**

- Only issue with this approach is that you will need to break the permission inheritance of each wiki page library and whenever a new library is created.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Could you please elaborate with an example how to achieve it, since I don't have much experience with all this.

Comment: I don't have the code sample handy at this moment, I'll update my answer with a sample shortly.

Comment: Is there any possibility that we can achieve this from central admin? like can we disable some feature for application from there.

Comment: From Central Admin, I don't think there is any such setting, but you can also do it via setting up your permissions on your in such a way that users can not create new items. Updating my answer for that option.

Answer (score 0):

We can only come up with (crazy) workarounds

Set a Workflow on the Wiki Library which:

- Deletes any new page
- sends an email to the creator:

  > We deleted the Wiki page you created, company rules... bla bla bla

Comment: If it's only wiki library then another option is to apply unique permissions around it.

Comment: The task is to prevent users from creating any of them in any site whether its new or old, anything in that direction please .